# Calculate the range automatically in a table (mysql)

Tags: mysql, range

For example,I have a table1:

```
      +------+----------+                                                         
      | num  | duration |                                           
      +------+----------+                                                    
      |   10 |        0 |
      |   15 |        1 |
      |    5 |        2 |
      |    7 |        3 |
      |   12 |        4 |
      |   13 |        5 |
      |    3 |        6 | 
      +------+----------+
```

in this table, the value of "duration" ranges from 0 to 6. "num" means how many flow's session duration is 0 or 1 or 2 etc. For example, the first row means there are 10 flows, their session duration is 0. The second row means there are 15 flows, their session duration is 1. 
Now, I want to calculate how many flow's session duration is larger than 0, larger than 1,larger than 2,larger than 3 ,etc.

```
select *
from 
( select sum(num) as totalnum,duration 
  from table1
  where duration >=
  (
    select duration from table1
  )
)as a;
```

But mysql mentions that "Subquery returns more than 1 row".
I want to get table like:

```
+-----------+----------+
| totalnum  | duration |
+-----------+----------+
|   65      |        0 |
|   55      |        1 |
|   40      |        2 |
|   35      |        3 |
|   28      |        4 |
|   16      |        5 |
|    3      |        6 |
+-----------+----------+
```

this table means : for example, the first row means there are 65 flows whose session duration is larger than 0.
The second row means there are55 flows whose session duration is larger than 1.
What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try joining the table onto itself where the join criteria is entries that have a duration greater than or equal to the duration in the FROM entry being processed:

```
SELECT SUM(T1up.num) AS totalnum, T1.duration
FROM table1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN table1 AS T1up
ON T1up.duration>=T1.duration
GROUP BY T1.duration;
```

Comment: Good one @Christopher McGowan

Comment: one edit required T1.duration in select.
otherwise it will be ambigous.